# A Ferris wheel has a radius of 20 m. Passengers get on halfway up on the right side.

Tags: trigonometry, physics

A [Ferris wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferris_wheel) has a radius of 20 m. Passengers get on halfway up on the right side. 
The direction of rotation is counter clockwise. The bottom of the Ferris wheel is 2 m
off the ground. It rotates every 36 seconds.

a)  Graph your height     above the ground as a function of time
[image]

b)  Determine a sine function that expresses your height as h as function of elapsed time t
h(t)=20sin(πt/18)+22

c) Determine your height above the ground after 15 seconds algebraically.

After 15 seconds:
h=20sin(15π/18)+22
=20sin(5π/6)+22
=20*(1/2)+22
=32 m

d) Determine the first time (to the nearest tenth) when your height is 38 m above the ground
            algebraically.

When h=38 m
38=20sin(πt/18)+22
38-22=20sin(πt/18)
20sin(πt/18)=16
sin(πt/18)=16/20=4/5=.8
arcsin(.8)=0.927
πt/18=0.927 (radians)
t=(.927*18)/π≈5.31

Height above the ground after 15 seconds≈38 m
seconds elapsed when height is 38 m above ground≈5.3 seconds

Comment: Currently Trying to add my solution...

Comment: The formula I got: h(t)=20sin(πt/18)+22

Comment: can someone have input on this if I'am correct and please help me graph....

Comment: `It rotates every 36 seconds`If that means a full rotation of the whel in 36 seconds, with a radius of $R=20m$ that gives $2\pi R/36 \approx 3{,5}$ meters per second. Isn't it a bit fast for passengers?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I was thinking the same thing: that is one HELL of a ferris wheel. I shudder to calculate the force the passengers are subjected to upon entering, leaving and even while on. Then I imagined it might stop to let passengers (dis-)embark, which would make the (de-)acceleration forces even worse. ... That thing is most likely a Death Trap!

Comment: @BMWurm Actually, I have since found this Wikipedia article about [Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_%28Ferris_wheel%29) in Missouri, and according to this article, its speed is $16 km/h$. In the example above, the speed would be $13 km/h$. Hence, even if I still think it's very fast, it's not unheard of.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut And here I thought rides on a ferris wheel where supposed to be relaxing, that one seems more like a thrill ride :P to each their own I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to part b is correct.  That is what you want to graph.  So plug in a number of $t$'s, get $h(t)$, and plot them.   If I were posing the problem, I would have asked b before a.

Added:  c and d are fine, as well.  A graph from Alpha is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eteffccp73a)

Comment: what about the rest